# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Input/output error

Tags: python-3.x, azure, tensorflow, pyspark, databricks

We are trying to play with the Tensorflow on Spark into Azure Databricks cluster using the python framework tensorflowonspark by yahoo.

**What we have done so far :**

Followed the instruction from this Databricks [thread](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/deep-learning/distributed-deep-learning/tfos.html).

Downloaded the Notebook and Successfully ran it on Azure Databricks cluster using pre-built MNIST .tfrecords

**When we are getting Error :**

Now, we have converted the MNIST to .tfrecords by this script. And uploaded to S3.
After that, whenever we are trying to launch the trainning script, we got stuck.

Here is the ERROR LOGS:

```
18/06/02 20:35:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 4)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
process()
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2438, in pipeline_func
return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 362, in func
return f(iterator)
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in func
r = f(it)
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflowonspark/TFSparkNode.py", line 353, in _mapfn
wrapper_fn(tf_args, ctx)
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflowonspark/TFSparkNode.py", line 310, in wrapper_fn
fn(args, context)
File "<command-4392809887925381>", line 31, in train
File "<command-4392809887925376>", line 40, in worker_function
File "<command-4392809887925444>", line 43, in add_optimizers_and_launch_sess
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 727, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
self._write_graph()
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 630, in _write_graph
self._logdir, "graph.pbtxt")
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_io.py", line 71, in write_graph
text_format.MessageToString(graph_def))
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 431, in atomic_write_string_to_file
rename(temp_pathname, filename, overwrite)
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 410, in rename
compat.as_bytes(oldname), compat.as_bytes(newname), overwrite, status)
File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: /dbfs/mnt/mnist-checkpoint-dir/graph.pbtxt.tmp2eed09f69a3443e0ac3c8ef02bdec6e0; Input/output error

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:303)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:443)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:951)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:951)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2166)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2166)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:349)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We couldn't find any threads related to this error.

As I am newbie to Distributed Tensorflow,any Help will be highly appreciable.